# Angular 5 - custom pipe 'could not be found' error

Tags: angular, angular5

I've tried all the suggestions I've seen out there but am still encountering the dreaded: `Template parse errors: The pipe 'orderFilter' could not be found`

In my SharedModule.ts (which imports MyComponent) I have:

```
import { OrderFilterPipe } from '../pipes/order-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
...
declarations: [OrderFilterPipe];
...
```

The pipe code (something simple for now):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'orderFilter'})
export class OrderFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(item: any): any {
    return item.data;
  }
}
```

In MyComponent.html I have:

```
{{item | orderFilter}}
```

I'm a bit at a loss.. unless I'm missing something in the implementation that's Angular 5 specific. Any ideas?

Comment: The error message mentions `myPipe`. Maybe you have that typo somewhere in your markup.

Comment: Why are you adding it as both a declaration and a provider? Remove it from providers. Also what you are attempting is directly discouraged in the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), just filter in the component use array methods or RxJS.

Comment: @ConnorsFan sorry, just a typo in my example - I changed the names to protect the innocent ;)

Comment: your delcarations property now has a typo.

Comment: When you say the SharedModule imports the component, what do you mean?  Are you adding the component to the 'imports' property in the module? You can only import other modules.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs fixed, thanks

Comment: @KeenanDiggs omg.. I found the root cause.. my app wasn't actually importing SharedModule.. it was importing MyComponent from a different module.. so that's why it couldn't find the filter. Ugh.. thanks, Keenan you helped track down the error in my code!

Comment: @brainmonter excellent! happy new year

Answer (score 3):

Try another name for your pipe, you can't name you pipe "filter".

Comment: I just used a bad example taken from my code - just updated to 'orderFilter' to remove confusion

Answer (score 2):

When we add any component or directive inside a shared module file so with adding that module inside declaration, we need to add into exports array as well.
Please see below code :

```
import { OrderFilterPipe } from '../pipes/order-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
declarations: [OrderFilterPipe],
exports: [OrderFilterPipe]     // you need to add this line
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when I remove the pipe from 'declarations' from the app.module in this minimal reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfi7v9

When I add it back, viola! Everything works. This leads me to believe the error is in the module that consumes your pipe module. Did you remember to import your pipe module into the module that MyComponent lives in?

Comment: Yes, I do see it working in your example. So strange why it's not in mind.. something I must be overlooking. Yes, the pipe is imported in the SharedModule, which MyComponent lives in

Comment: There's no tslint error in my template either.. it's just for some reason at run time it cannot find it and throws that error

Answer (score 0):

[Ionic/ angular] Might be the solution works if the source have each page specific mouldes. You must add the pipe module to each page specific modules to get it work.

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { RegisterOnePage } from "./register-one";
 import { PipesModule } from '../../../pipes/pipes.module';

 @NgModule({
  declarations: [RegisterPage],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(RegisterPage),
    PipesModule
  ]
})
export class RegisterPageModule {}
```